# Ciclo while no me devuelve el primer valor de la consulta Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, while

Buen día hoy me dí cuenta de que mi código no enlista el primer valor de la consulta a mysql

```
 Try
    cnn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select DISTINCT Peine from Peines where ubicacion = 'Almacen'", cnn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Rs.Read()
    While Rs.Read
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Rs(0))
    End While
    cnn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    cnn.Close()
End Try
```

¿estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: si, sobra un read..

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estas ejecutando una consulta con `ExecuteNonQuery`, que solo te devuelve un resultado y no en la forma de `recordset` (que es el objeto que quieres consultar para ver los resultados devueltos. Tienes que utilizar `ExecuteReader`.

Por lo tanto tu código quedaría mas o menos:

```
...
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select DISTINCT Peine from Peines where ubicacion = 'Almacen'", cnn)
Dim Rs as SqlDatReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
// Rs.Read() Debes obviarlo, con el while posterior ya haces el primer Read()
While Rs.Read
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Rs(0))
End While
...
```

Comment: Ya que vamos a corregirle toda la funcion, el cnn.Close() tranquilamente podria ir en un finally...

Comment: El problema era el primer Rs.Read()  muchas gracias por la ayuda